# Exploring a strange isomorphism on class groups

Tags: group-theory, number-theory

I bumped into the following fact. Let $F$ be a number field. Let $C = \prod p^{n_p}$ with each $n_p$ large enough so that if $ord_p(a-1) > n_p$, then $a$ is a square in $F_v$.

Let $S$ a finite set of places containing the archimedean ones. Let $I$ be the group of fractional ideals prime to $S$, and $P$ its subgroup of totally positive principal ideals $(x)$ such that $x \equiv 1 \text{ mod } C$ (that is to say, locally $x_v$ is a square in $F_v$). The following isomorphism is stated in a paper by Fisher and Friedberg without explanation:

> $$(I/P) \otimes \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} = I/I^2 P.$$

Could someone explains me the reasons for that?